# how to move files that contain string using find, xargs, grep, in linux

Tags: grep, find, xargs, mv

i have many php files maybe over Three million..
how can i use grep with xargs and find with mv to find contain the string in files and move them to directory if they match.

I try like that

```
find . -iname \*.php\* | xargs -n64 grep -hEl 'to times' | xargs -0 -I {} mv {} old/
```

that doesn't do anything.

but if i run without the second xargs i got result like this...right files

```
./20150713094500*/vb/showthread.php?p=10297131
./20150715080347*/vb/showthread.php?t=1133875&page=3
./20150630233104*/vb/member.php?find=lastposter&t=1234502
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find files that matches `'*.php*`

```
find . -type f -name '*.php*' |
```

then pass each file name to `grep` which will output only file names if 'to times' string wil be found

```
xargs -I {} grep -l 'to times' '{}' |
```

then pass each file name to `mv`

```
xargs -I {} mv '{}' old/
```

Comment: ... this work with me . thanks for your help & for the simplified explanation.